# Spring Cloud Netflix: Are Zuul "Post" filters guaranteed to be called?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

When leveraging Spring MVC, we can leverage interceptors to "pre" and "post" handle requests.  Specifically, we can set up resources (thread locals for example) in the prehandle method and be guaranteed an opportunity to clean up those resources in the afterCompletion/afterConcurrentHandlingStarted methods.

Thinking about Zuul filters, if we set up resources in a "Pre" filter, do we have the same guarantee that the "Post" filter will be called?  Is there a better way to initialize/cleanup thread locals using this programming model?

thanks,

Joshua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code: https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/ it looks like if there are exceptions in "pre" or "route", "error" filters are run, then "post" filters.  If an exception happens during any type ("pre" or "route", etc..), the rest of the filters are skipped, so if your post filter is first, I'd say it will be called.